# Xcode 4 adding images to a project

Tags: xcode, file, project

Coming from a background of Visual Studio I had no idea how good that IDE truly was until I had to work with Xcode. One of the more pressing oddities that it has just thrown up is the following.

I'm upgrading a project to a retina display and so have to add a bunch of new @X2 files. This is fine, I have the files and I go into Xcode, choose the project group where I want to add them, select them all and click 'Add'.

"Multiple errors occured" Xcode helpfully blurts and then returns to whatever it was doing before. No break down of what those errors might be, or what actually happened or why.

So I do some looking and some of the files are actually in the directory but Xcode ignores them, I can't figure out a way of adding them (it says they're already there!) but they won't appear in the xcode project.

Can I 'refresh' xcode so it looks in the directory and shows them?

==============================

PS. While I'm here and can rant a little, anyone with a VS background now using Xcode, am I wrong in thinking the following points are hugely annoying:

1) The debugger - frustratingly slow.

2) The file explorer - can't easily sort by name

3) The file explorer - column on the right listing the file names doesn't change the file highlight when you move from file to file within the editor window.

4) Adding files to a project - see above!

Some of these probably stem from lack of experience with the IDE but still, they irk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Files in the XCode directories don't necessarily have to be in the project.

For some reason, XCode doesn't like overwriting files, and that's the warning message that I usually get when this happens too - "Multiple errors occured."

What I suggest you do is remove all of the @2x files from your project directory, and add them back into XCode using "Add Files..." Make sure you select "Copy files into project directory if necessary" though, otherwise they will just be referenced to their current location on disk.

Comment: This turned out to be the problem alright, combined with an SVN issue that was stopping all copying. Why does XCode stop you copying over files? It's so annoying when you select a bunch of files which you think are new and add them to the project - turns out one of them is already there and the entire import fails!

Comment: Yes, it is quite annoying, especially the error message that is totally useless! No idea why it stops copying of files. As you said, VS seems to be able to cope with this perfectly well.

Comment: Very indeed. I will file a bug report with apple